# Prime divisors of certain consecutive integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples

A question in ring theory lead me to a system of diophantine inequalities. I have problems to solve it, but a positive answer of the following would bring me some effort:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \neq 9$ and $P = \max \{p \in \mathbb{P} \mid p \leq n\} $.

- Does there exist $r \in \{P+1,...,n\}$ such that there exists $q \in \mathbb{P}$ with $q | r$ and $q > n - P + 1$?
- Can we say something about the number of $r \in \{ P+1,...,n \}$ that satisfy this statement (in relation to the difference $n - P$)?

I have really no idea to approach this and I also cannot find a counterexample.
I would be really glad if somebody could help me!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is very unlikely that we can prove the existence of $q$ for every $n$, so we should search for a counterexample.

Comment: If $M_p = 2^p - 1$ is a Mersenne prime, and $n = M_p + 1$, then $\{ P+1, \ldots, n\} = \{n\} = \{2^p\}$, while $n - P + 1 = 2$, so no $q > n - P + 1$ divides any $r \in \{P+1, \ldots, n\}$. If you exclude such situations, there might always be an $r$.

Comment: Thank you! Very nice!